# Windows: creating Jekyll pages not working

Tags: jekyll

Unable to render new page in browser. I'm on Win7 and have Ruby1.9.3 and DevKit installed. When I create a new Jekyll site everything works. I copied the index.html in root and renamed to about.html and that worked and was able to view both pages in the browser. I copied the about.html page and renamed to contact.html and the page fails to inherit the layout and only renders text content and Liquid tags in the browser. All of this is on my local machine. Thanks for any advice.

Repo: https://github.com/greenlightjspence/JekyllWin7/

Comment: It would help if we could see some code. Can you push your repository to github?

Comment: This is a weird issue. If I create a new html file and add front-matter and markup the page fails when viewing in the browser. If I copy one of the existing html files in the root and rename it, it works fine. Has anyone else run into this issue before? I'm using VS2012.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem today and after almost hour fighting with it I finally found that Visual Studio saved my file with 'UTF-8 with Signature' encoding which was causing issues. Changing file encoding to 'UTF-8 without Signature' helped. To change file encoding, open file (index.html in my case) and go to File->Advanced Save Options. Hope it will help you as well.

Looks like it's known issue mentioned on official Jekyll site (http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/).