# Using layout as a base for another layout

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm following this tutorial [github pages](http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/) as is.

```
_layouts/
  |
   -- default.html
   -- post.html

_posts/ 
  |
   -- 2015-09-29-example-site-launched.md
```

But the `post.html` doesn't seem to be using the `default.html` layout.

This is what i get:

[image]

What might i be doing wrong?

Comment: This is strange. Can you post you github repository url ?

Comment: Try structuring the YAML frontmatter with `---` and then a new line, and then only `layout: default` and then another new line, and then only `---`, this might be a YAML parse issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem was with visual studio as this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20600338/852243) solves my problem.